# DropBox API how to get the Access Code Generated using Postman

Tags: postman, dropbox-api, postman-newman

I am having a problem automating on how to get the access key generated(refer to access key generated image below) using Postman without      manually place the path in browser and manually get the access key generated. I tried to POST request this:`

```
https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<API KEY>&token_access_type=offline&response_type=code
```

the result will be 200OK but I can't locate the access key in the logs/console.  `

[access key generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3GQc.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp2o7.png)

Comment: You might want to remove your client ID and access tokens from any of the screenshots you've added.

Answer (score 0):

[www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize](http://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize) is a web page, and not an API endpoint, and so should not be accessed programmatically, e.g., in Postman. It should be accessed by the user in their system browser.

It is not possible to fully automate the OAuth process where the user chooses to authorize the app and the app then receives the resulting access token and optional refresh token. This needs to be done manually by the user at least once. If your app needs to maintain long-term access without the user manually re-authorizing it repeatedly, the app should request "offline" access so that it gets a refresh token. The refresh token doesn't expire and can be stored and used repeatedly to get new short-lived access tokens whenever needed, without the user manually reauthorizing the app.

You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization). There's a basic outline of processing this flow in [this blog post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access) which may serve as a useful example.